# Экспорт apk Unity билда под новые устройства без исходника

Tags: unity3d, deserialize

мне поставили нестандартную задачу. Мне скинули apk файл и кеш игры. Исходники были очень давно утеряны. Попросили восстановить работоспособность игры на Android 6 и выше. На Android 5 игра работает отлично.Я подумал, что можно как-нибудь залить ее в Android Studio и от туда забилдить под новые устройства. Не подскажете что делать в той ситуации?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.